# Position a div at the bottom of an absolute div without using tables or positoin:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a webapp that needs a div to be pushed to the bottom of another absolutely positioned div.  I have tried `bottom: 0` and `vertical-align: bottom` with neither of them working.  Is there some way to move a div to the bottom of its parent div using CSS that I may not have thought of or some sort of workaround that could be done using JavaScript?

```css
#wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 z-index: 1000;
}
#outer {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 1001;
}
#a {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: 100%;
}
#inner {
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
.invert {
    color:white;
}
.revert {
    color:black;
}
.text-center {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outer" class="invert">
        <div id="a">
             <h3 class="text-center">Words!</h3>
             <h4 class="text-center">0 - 0</h4>
            <div id="inner">
                <span class="revert">This needs to be at the bottom</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `position: absolute`?

Comment: Can you modify your markup? If you move `<div id="inner" >` from being a child of `#a` to being an immediate child of `#outer` then it's trivial to get it to work.

Comment: When I have used `position: absolute` in this, it has made the div that should be moved to the bottom just completely vanish from the page.  if there is a way to not make it vanish, or mess up any other spacing, I would love to see it.

Comment: @Dai When I do that, and set the inner div's CSS to `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`, the div jumps to the very bottom of the window, not the bottom of the div that is colored black in the demo.  I made a jsfiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/u0uhrmza/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See code below.  Also, read up on the `position` property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
#wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 z-index: 1000;
}
#outer {
    position: relative; /* <-- add this -------------- */
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 1001;
}
#a {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;  /* <-- change this -------------- */
    width: 100%; /* <-- to this -------------- */
    height: 100%;
}
#inner {
    position: absolute; /* <-- add this -------------- */
    width: 100%; /* <-- add this -------------- */
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
.invert {
    color:white;
}
.revert {
    color:black;
}
.text-center {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outer" class="invert">
        <div id="a">
             <h3 class="text-center">Words!</h3>
             <h4 class="text-center">0 - 0</h4>
            <div id="inner">
                <span class="revert">This needs to be at the bottom</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had done something similar to this, but I think I only had half of it at a time.  Thanks!